# Downstream GFCI protection vs NEC code requirements

Tags: electrical

If I have an outlet, which by code needs to be "GFCI protected", and that outlet is downstream from a GCFI outlet, is it in lines with the code requirements, or does the outlet itself need to be a GFCI outlet?

Answer (score 3):

GFCI protection extends to circuits; including any devices, that are connected to the LOAD side terminals of a GFCI device. This means that if the wires feeding the circuit beyond the GFCI are connected to the LOAD terminals of the GFCI, then the downstream circuit is GFCI protected.

A simple test is to plug something into the receptacle that you need protected, then press the TEST button on the upstream GFCI device.  If the plugged in item turns off, then the receptacle that it's attached to is GFCI protected. When you press the TEST button on a GFCI device, anything that is protected by that device will lose power (unless of course the GFCI device has malfunctioned).

Comment: I like your simpler simple test-- I overthought it with the GFCI tester.

Comment: That is a fantastic test tip.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, yes it should be protected.

The outlet is GFCI protected assuming that its LINE side is supplied by the LOAD side of the GFCI. If the actual GFCI receptacle was installed using pigtails, this leave your "downstream" receptacles unprotected.

Check your receptacle in question using a GFCI tester to be certain.

[image: GFCI outlet tester]